# Adding double quotes to a string in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'm sorry for being a regex newbie, but I have a Json-like string like this:

```
{
foo:foostring,
bar:barstring
}
```

And I need to add double quotes to every string to make it look like a real Json

```
{
"foo":"foostring",
"bar":"barstring"
}
```

I've already done this:

```
val jsonString = oldString.replaceAll("(\\w+)", "\"$1\"")
```

And it works! The problem is, these "foostring" and "barstrings" are generated authomatically and sometimes they include "-". When that happens, my regex fails and it escapes the hyphen like this:

```
{
"foo":"foo"-"string",
"bar":"bar"-"string"
}
```

I have no idea how to make the doble quotes include that "-" Symbol.

Any help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just match with a combined class `[...]` of `\w` and `-`, but make sure that the hyphen does not appear in a position where it has special meaning for regex (like range `A-Z`).

For example:

```
val oldString = """{
foo:foostring,
bar:barstring,
baz:baz-string
}"""

val jsonString = oldString.replaceAll("([\\w-]+)", "\"$1\"")

println(jsonString)
```

prints out:

```
{
"foo":"foostring",
"bar":"barstring",
"baz":"baz-string"
}
```